# Select divs with similar pattern in ids

Tags: jquery, html, regex, css, css-selectors

So i have divs with ids like `id=1_due_date` or `id=2_due_date`

```
<div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1_due_date" name="1_due_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
</div> 

<div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="2_due_date" name="2_due_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
</div>
```

In the same way there will be many divs with number in front of them changing like 10_due_date.How can i select all these divs using jquery.
I am trying with regex expression like this `$('[id^="[1-9]"][id$="_due_date"]')` but i am not getting the desired result.Any suggestions will be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in jQuery. Here is a quick sneak peek on different selectors that you can use for various operations-

1. **$('input[id*="due_date"]')** - Selects all elements that have the `id` attribute with a value containing `due_date` substring like `123_due_date_456`, `due_date_11`, `xyz_due_date`, etc.
2. **$('input[id$="due_date"]')** - Selects elements that have `id` with a value ending exactly with `due_date` like `1_due_date`, `XYZdue_date`, etc. The comparison is case sensitive.
3. **$('input[id^="due_date"]')** - Selects elements that have the `id` attribute with a value beginning exactly with `due_date`, like `due_date_1`, `due_date123`, etc.

In your case, since you want to check if the `id` ends with suffix `due_date`, you should use `$('input[id$="due_date"]')` like below-

```js
$('input[id$="due_date"]').val("Match found");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1_due_date" name="1_due_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="2_due_date" name="2_due_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
  <div class="form-group" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qwe" name="2_due_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
</div>
```

Comment: got my divs selected properly.thanks for saving my day.Dont have enough points to upvote your answer

Comment: @yogeshmanjhi Glad to be of help! PS - please upvote if this helped! :)

Comment: Ahh, no problem then.. Have a great day!

Comment: will upvote it once i have enough points.Good deeds always return. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('input[id*="due_date"]').css("background-color", 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="1_due_date" name="1_due_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="2_due_date" name="2_due_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
  <div class="form-group" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qwe" name="2_due_date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
</div>
```

1. Use wildcard with attribute selector.

***Note:***

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: thanks now i got the div selected properly.thanks for saving my day.